# How to update array element using setState in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I had an array structure similar to this:

```
person[{id: 0, firstname: 'john', surname: 'smith'}, 
       {id: 1, firstname: 'jane', surname: 'smith'}]
```

Then using an event handler to catch some change and using setState, how could I update the array element similar to this:

```
handleChangeEvent(newSurname, id){
     this.setState({ person[id].surname : newSurname})
}
```

Comment: Do you want it to add a new entry if the id doesn't exist and update an entry if the id does exist?

Comment: I'm looking at accomplishing this on the presumption that the ID does in fact exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setState()`'s [updater callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) to perform your state change in a single atomic operation without the risk of overwriting (or being overwritten by) other state changes to the component in the same event tick:

```
handleChangeEvent(surname, id) {
    this.setState(({ people }) => ({
        people: people.map(
            person => person.id === id ? { ...person, surname } : person
        )
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try something along the lines of:

```
handleChangeEvent(newSurname, id){
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    people: prevState.people.map(
      person => person.id === id ? { ...person, surname: newSurname } : person
    )
  }));
}
```

In this code snippet we are getting a reference to your `people` array in your component's state. Then we are filtering this array based on `ids` and if the `id` matches the person whose name needs to be updated we set the `surname` appropriately. Otherwise, we just return the existing object if the `id` doesn't match the person who needs to be updated.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Would be better to use the updater callback signature of `setState()` for atomicity since the new state is derived from the previous one. e.g. `this.setState(prev => prev.map(person => ...))`

Comment: Now your answer is no different than mine, other than syntax...

Answer (score 0):

This is basically what you are looking for. I'd however recommend you to use a library like immer to create immutable objects.

```
handleChangeEvent(newSurname, id){
     this.setState({
                     people : Array.from(this.state.people, person => {
                          if(person[id] === id)
                           return {...person, surname: newSurname}
                          return person
                     })   
     })
}
```